# How to create SUMO output files in OMNET++?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo, inet

I am trying to generate the raw dump of SUMO (https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Output/RawDump.html) for my simulation that is running with SUMO and OMNET++.

I have added the lines:
`<output> <netstate-dump value="crossroads.output.xml" /> </output>`

to my sumo.cfg file as required but no output file is being created. Does anyone know if there is anything else I have to add, maybe to the omnetpp.ini file?

Comment: Please double check that you added that line to the right config. Where did you add it and which command did you run afterwards?

Comment: I added it to the sumo.cfg file in omnet++ in the simulations folder. After that I simply ran the simulation as usual in omnet++ using the IDE.

Comment: Can you maybe just add a typo to this file so that it will fail and you know you are editing the right file?

Comment: If I add a typo the simulation does not launch, so I think it is the correct file

Comment: Could you check whether other outputs such as tripinfo or fcd work?

Comment: @Michael No files are created when I put either of those outputs, sry for taking so long I had a big sim running

Comment: Maybe try with an absolute path such as "/tmp/crossroads.output.xml" to make sure they are not in an unexpected directory